# C# Console App - LINQ to find matching values between two IEnumerables

Tags: c#, linq

I'm having some issues construction a LINQ query to find MATCHING values in two IEnumerables I have from CSV files and outputting those matching values to another list for some bookkeeping later on in my application.

My classes for the IEnumerables and the related code (using CSVHelper) to read the CSVs into the IEnumerables are below. Any input on where to begin, LINQ query wise, to find those matching values and output to a list? I'm relatively new to LINQ (usually use SQL in the backend) and I'm finding it a bit difficult to do exactly what I want to.

CLASSES:

```
class StudentSuccessStudents
{
    [CsvColumn(Name ="StudentID", FieldIndex = 1)]
    public string StudentID { get; set; }
}
class PlacementStudents
{
    [CsvColumn(Name = "StudentId", FieldIndex = 1)]
    public string StudentId { get; set; }

}
```

PROGRAM:

```
CsvFileDescription inputCsvStuSuccess = new CsvFileDescription
            {
                SeparatorChar = ',',
                FirstLineHasColumnNames = true,
                EnforceCsvColumnAttribute = false
            };
            CsvContext ccStuSuccess = new CsvContext();

            CsvFileDescription inputCsvStuScores = new CsvFileDescription
            {
                SeparatorChar = ',',
                FirstLineHasColumnNames = false,
                EnforceCsvColumnAttribute = true
            };
            CsvContext ccStuScores = new CsvContext();

            IEnumerable<StudentSuccessStudents> students = ccStuSuccess.Read<StudentSuccessStudents>(filePath, inputCsvStuSuccess);
            IEnumerable<PlacementStudents> outputStudents = ccStuScores.Read<PlacementStudents>(csvPath, inputCsvStuScores);
```

Any suggestions on how to get all my "StudentID" fields in the first list that match a "StudentId" in the second one to output to another list with LINQ? I basically need to have that "matching" list so I can safely ignore those values elsewhere.

Comment: `List<string> matchingIds = students.Where(s => outputStudents.Any(o => o.StudentId == s.StudentID)).Select(s => s.StudentID).ToList();`

Comment: Ah! I don't know why I was overthinking this so much. Thank you! Will try this out--but I'm all but certain it's exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: Hmm, so, using the following:
List<string> matchingIds = students.Where(student => outputStudents.Any(output => output.StudentId == student.StudentID)).Select(student => student.StudentID).ToList();
I'm getting a Null reference exception on Any(output => output.StudentId == student.StudentID))
Does that mean there are no matches?

Comment: It most likely means that `outputStudents` is `null`. What is the specific exception message?. Set a breakpoint and examine the values...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always use the [SQL syntax of Linq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/query-syntax-and-method-syntax-in-linq) like shown below. This way it looks more like something you're use to, and gets you the duplicate values you need. Also looks more readable (in my opinion) too.

```
var duplicates = from success in students 
                 join placement in outputStudents on success.StudentID equals placement.StudentId
                 select success.StudentID;
```

Comment: That's much more like I'm used to! Unfortunately, I get an error in VS2019: PlacementStudents in the JOIN statement "is a type, which is not valid in the given context."

Comment: @LoganSBishop that's becuase the variables weren't being used, the types were. I updated the answer to reflect that, so it shouldn't give you that error now.

Comment: I realized that about five minutes after I posted--thanks for the update! This works BEAUTIFULLY and in a way I understand much better than the LINQ syntax. I'm getting a null reference exception after the join query, though, when I try to run the resulting var ToList() and then do a foreach to write the results to console for testing purposes,which I'm assuming means I have no matches?

Comment: Glad that helped! Could be, could also be the start of a new question haha. I made a list of 5 for each one that had 2 duplicates to check locally. You can  try that and/or step though the execution to see where it dies on null at.

Answer (score 0):

This is a **linq operator to do this functionality** called Intersect so

If they were both the same type you could do this

```
var result = students.Intersect(outputStudents);
```

Which should be the fastest way.

Since they are different types you do this

```
var result = students.Intersect(outputStudents.Select(x => new StudentSuccessStudent(x.id) );
```

basically you create a new list of the correct type dynamically

This is an example where inheritance or interfaces are powerful.  If they both inherited from the same type then you could intersect on that type and C# would solve this problem super fast.

Comment: This doesn't work... the `StudentSuccessStudents` class need to override the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods to use the `ID` property for comparison. Otherwise `Intersect` uses the default comparison, which uses reference equality.